# window.event not working in Firefox

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble with window.event working in Firefox - it works perfectly in chrome. This is my code:

```
private myFunction(event:any) {
   if(window.event.target.outerHTML.indexOf('point') > -1){
    return;
};
```

The error is:

> window.event is undefined

I have looked at some similar questions posted and tried the following which didnt work either:

```
private myFunction(event:any) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    if(e.target.outerHTML.indexOf('point') > -1){
        return;
    };  
}
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: That doesn't really look like javascript. Anyway, a quick Google search should tell you that `window.event` is an IE thing, and chrome just adopted it, it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: Sorry, its TypeScript...a superset of javascript. Javascript is valid TypeScript though so if you know how to do it in javascript I can just do it like that

Comment: The error is at the point of registering the listener. Show that code

Comment: The first one doesn't work since `event` isn't [defined on window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window) in Firefox. It isn't clear why the second one is failing from the code example.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you attach the event to a dom element. You cannot rely on the event argument in your callback because there are some differences in how the older browsers (<=IE8) does this and in addition, as you already found Firefox does also work slightly different.

You can read something about correct dom event attachment here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener
there is also an example to implement support for IE8 which is not too bad.

But in general I'd suggest to use some kind of library which does event handling for you. 
Because this is quite complex and very easy to do wrong, those libraries are really helpful (not only in this regard)...

First option would be JQuery, but there are many other JavaScript libraries out there. And you can use them in Typescript of course with downloading the corresponding typing.

@see http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/off/